# Keras model/layer regularization property deprecated

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras to define a model, then I try to calibrate it using Distributed Tensorflow, as is done [here](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/2c9b029f505d94e6b8cd7f8a5e244a4e).

I used to deal with regularizer loss as done in the link

```
model = Sequential()
...... #build keras model
loss = tf.reduce_mean(keras.objectives.mean_squared_error(targets, preds))
# apply regularizers if any
if model.regularizers:
    total_loss = loss * 1.  # copy tensor
    for regularizer in model.regularizers:
        total_loss = regularizer(total_loss)
else:
    total_loss = loss
```

But now the regularizers property is depricated and a warning suggests to use `losses` property of `model/layer` so I tried :

```
 loss = tf.reduce_mean(keras.objectives.mean_squared_error(targets, preds))
 total_loss = loss * 1.  # copy tensor
 for reg_loss in model.losses:
     tf.assign_add(total_loss, reg_loss)
```

But this causes a crash. Any help please

Comment: What is the crash ? Any message to post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct thing to do is simply :

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(keras.objectives.mean_squared_error(targets, preds))
total_loss = loss * 1.  # copy tensor
for reg_loss in model.losses:
total_loss = total8loss + reg_loss
```